# Dialling a SIP number

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, phone-app, sip

So I have a very, very shiny new Nexus 4. This supports SIP, and I have added a SIP account to the telephony accounts settings page.

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to actually *dial* a SIP number. How do I do this?

The telephone dialer has number buttons only, and tapping the number entry field doesn't pop up a keyboard. Rumour has it that previous versions of Android had a 'text' button somewhere on the dialer page, but that's not present in JB. There must be some way to do it...

(Note: I'm not asking how to add a SIP number to a contact. I know how to do that. I want to dial numbers that aren't on my contacts list.)

**Update:** after some experimenting, I have found that:

- pressing the DIAL button with the field empty reloads the text field with the last number dialed, which can be a SIP number of the form sip:music@iptel.org. So I know the text field is *capable* of handling text.
- trying to paste text into the field produces gibberish. For the above number, I get 7476874247835.674! (Which is what the letters on the dial pad map to. Except for : and @, which are emitted.) Dialing this number does nothing --- obviously.

Comment: Have you tried long-pressing the menu "button"? On most devices I've tried, this brings up the keyboard. Not sure if this way you could enter the SIP ID to be called -- but it would be worth a try ;)

Comment: A good thought, but unfortunately it doesn't work... also, I have discovered some weirdness. See update.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple app specifically for this task: https://github.com/whitequark/SIPCaller

Comment: Hi, we appreciate your app to solve this issue, but is there any link to the released app? Considering that Android Enthusiasts focus on Android end-users who are not necessarily developers, they may not be able to compile and use the app by themselves.

Comment: Sure: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.whitequark.sipcaller/